# Range Inputs Sliders Combination Should always sum 100% [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, rangeslider

I'm totally new to this.
I want to create interactive range sliders, for example, if I have 4 range sliders when I increase/decrease one slider, the others should decrease/increase to keep the sum of all percentages equal to 100%.
Note that the sliders number differ for each loop, here's my HTML code:
Each layer contains multiple files and each file has its own range slider.

```
<div class="tab-content">
{{#each layers}}
  <div class="tab-pane" id={{this.layers}}>
   {{#each this.files}}      
       <div class="range-wrap">
           <input id="rangeInput" class="range" name="rangeInput" type="range" min="1" max="100" onchange="function()"/>
       </div>
   {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: The question is: when you move slider 2, for example, to be greater, which slider do you want to be subtracted from? Would you want it to be the first one? The last?

Comment: range sliders inside each layer must sum 100%; only inside the layer, I mean, for example, first layer contains slider1,slider2, and slider3 these 3 layers should sum 100%